How to express the definite integral of this hyperelliptic integral as the definite integral of the elliptic integral
How to express the definite integral of this hyperelliptic integral as the definite integral of the elliptic integral?
Using the substitution formula
\begin{cases}
p=e^{-\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} t^2+\frac{e^{\frac{2 i \pi}{5}}}{t^2}\\
q=e^{\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} t^2+\frac{e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}}}{t^2}
\end{cases}
we can get the following definite integral, but there are many discontinuous points, so I want to express this hyperelliptic integral as an elliptic integral with real variables:
\begin{align*}
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t^{20}}}\\
&=\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{8}+\frac{i}{4}\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}}\right)\int_{e^{\frac{2i\pi}{5}}\infty}^{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^{5}-5p^{3}+5p}}\mathrm{d}p\\
&\qquad-\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{8}+\frac{i}{4}\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}}\right)\int_{e^{-\frac{2i\pi}{5}}\infty}^{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}\frac{q}{\sqrt{q^{5}-5q^{3}+5q}}\mathrm{d}q
\end{align*}
\begin{gather*}
\int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^{5}-5t^{3}+5t}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\\
=\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2x\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}x+\sqrt{5}}}}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{10\sqrt{25-10\sqrt{5}}}}{10}}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-(\raise{1pt}{\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
+\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2x\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}x+\sqrt{5}}}}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{10\sqrt{25-10\sqrt{5}}}}{10}}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-(\raise{1pt}{\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^{5}-5t^{3}+5t}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\\
=\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2x\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}x+\sqrt{5}}}}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{10\sqrt{25-10\sqrt{5}}}}{10}}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-(\raise{1pt}{\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
-\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2x\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}x+\sqrt{5}}}}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{10\sqrt{25-10\sqrt{5}}}}{10}}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-(\raise{1pt}{\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{gather*}
You can use the following Mathematica code to simply verify an integral equation numerically:
(NIntegrate[(1/8 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) + I 1/4 Sqrt[1/10 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) p/
     Sqrt[p^5 - 5 p^3 + 5 p], {p, 
    Limit[E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/5)) x^2 + E^((2 I \[Pi])/5)/x^2, x -> 0], 
    1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] - 
  NIntegrate[(-(1/8) (-1 + Sqrt[5]) + 
      I 1/4 Sqrt[1/10 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) q/Sqrt[q^5 - 5 q^3 + 5 q], {q, 
    Limit[E^((2 I \[Pi])/5) x^2 + E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/5))/x^2, x -> 0], 
    1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, WorkingPrecision -> 20])
(NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x^20 + 1], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20])

I want an exact expression for the elliptic integral, expressing the upper and lower limits of the integral in algebraic form.

For what it's worth, the integral of interest can be expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function as ${2}F{1}(1/20,1/2;21/20;-1)$.
